# Extracting string within brackets, if it doesnt contain another string

Tags: regex

I want to do a search of some markup and look for a certain tag that doesn't contain a certain attribute.
If the tag is {mytag} and the attribute is bold, I want to find occurences of mytag where bold is missing.

find this:
{mytag size=3}

ignore this:
{mytag bold="true" size=3}

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for parsing non regular languages.

Comment: What sort of markup is this? For most markup there are robust parsers widely available (e.g. HtmlAgilityPak for HTML).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
{mytag([^}](?!bold=))*}
```

It'll match your tag, and using negative look-ahead make sure the `bold` tag appears before the ending `}`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dJ9hN8/2).

As comments says, regex isn't ideal here. Say an attribute contains a `}` it would fail. E.g. `{mytag name="abc}def" bold="true"}`

Regards